# Android: Parse Unknown JSON Tags

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

After having searched a lot with no result, I finally deciding to ask this question here.

This is an excerpt from this Facebook blog post: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/592/

```
{
 . . .
      "story": "Dhiren Patel likes Marmot.",
      "story_tags": {
        "19": [
          {
            "id": 101961456910,
            "name": "Marmot",
            "offset": 19,
            "length": 6
          }
        ],
        "0": [
          {
            "id": 1207059,
            "name": "Dhiren Patel",
            "offset": 0,
            "length": 12
          }
        ]
      }, 
 . . .
}
```

I am using the example above from the blog linked but essentially, the data set when using the FB Graph API is the same. Now, I know how to parse `JSONObjects` as well `JSONArrays` with nesting and all. But I am clueless with this kind of data. **19** and **0** in the example are determined by the nested `offset` tag and changes from post to post. How can I account for unknown JSON tags and code to get the information within them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand, the problem you have is you don't know how to get the keys, which are dynamically generated depending on posts or something else (for example as in json: **19, 0**). Here is the way you should parse this JSON:

```
JSONObject mStoryTags = mMainObj.getJSONObject("story_tags");
if(mStoryTags != null){
    Iterator<Object> keys = mStoryTags.keys();
    while(keys.hasNext()){
        String id = String.valueOf(keys.next()); // This value represent 19
        JSONArray mTag = mStoryTags.getJSONArray(id);
        if(mTag != null){
            for(int i = 0; i < mTag.length();i++){
                JSONObject mElem = mTag.getJSONObject(i);
                if(mElem != null){
                    int objectId = mElem.getInt("id"); // value: 101961456910
                    // and etc.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps to anyone who has the same problem! : )

Comment: I had almost forgotten about this question. Eventually, it wasn't so stringent a requirement and I absolutely overlooked it. Got time to test it a while back after you posted it yesterday. Thanks a lot. ;-)

Comment: You welcome, I had problems with JSON like this a while ago and I made a big research until I found out how to parse it, so glad I helped! : )

Answer (score 0):

If you have a JSONObject that represents the "story_tags" scope above, you should be able to iterate through the individual tags with:

```
for (String key : storyTagsJSON.keys()) {
    JSONObject tagJSON = storyTagsJSON.optJSONObject(key);
    ...
```

Comment: Can you explain this just a tad please? Will this take care of the variables? The **19** and **0** in the example

Comment: Yes.  Unless I am misunderstanding your question, in the example you gave, the first time through the loop, key would be "19".  The second time through key would be "0".  And I missed that the contents are an array, so my second line should have used JSONArray/optJSONArray instead of JSONObject/optJSONObject.

Comment: Not quite actually. When I mean variable, I mean that the **19** and **0** can be just about anything. In one post they might even be, for instance, say **29**, **16** and **2**. The tags under the `story_tags` can change from post to post and therefore, they cannot be accounted for at run time.

Comment: Right.  Calling .keys() on the "story_tags" JSONObject gives you the list of property names of that JSONObject.  In your first example it would give you a list containing "19" and "0", and in your other example it would give you a list containing "29", "16", and "2".

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I will give that suggestion a try and report back.